# url question mark (javascript sample, how to do it)

Tags: javascript, parsing, url

Sorry but English is not my mother language. I need a sample on how to make something like this:

I have category and URL is like:

```
/category
```

and I want to parse url in javascript to be like this

```
/category?group=myFirstGroup
```

I don't know how to express myself, I hope you will understand me. Another example would be like this:

---

There is a website e.g. www.abc.com with /help section with frequently asked questions for doctors and patients.

I want to give url to people with just questions for **doctors** or **patients**, not all questions in one place. Example:

www.abc.com/help?type=doctors (contain just questions for doctors)
www.abc.com/help?type=patients (contain just questions for patients)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a JavaScript specific question. If I understand you right you are talking about query parameters in the context of RESTful Web Services. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I guess it's RESTful, not really JS. I don't know how to ask properly question. Can you tell me what should I google?

Comment: Look at the link provided on top of your question whether this is what you need. If not search for query parameter or REST in general to get a understanding.